# how i can add methods to method Dictionary

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

i tried to add a method from self method Dictionary to another object method Dictionary while run time,but i didn't succeed, I am tried to do:

```
(self methodDict keys) do:[:funDec| 
MyObject methodDict at: funDec put: (self methodDic at: funDec).].
```

how i can add methods from method Dictionary to anothor in a right way?

Comment: "but I didn't succeed".... exactly what's gone wrong? Error message? Erroneous results? What context are you calling this in? Are you in an instance method? Class method? You also have errors.  There is no `methodDic` selector.

Comment: i get error message => "Error: primSize: failed". I tried to add a instance method to his class methodDictionary

Comment: What's the context within which you're calling this? What is `self` referring to?

Comment: self refer to class not a instance

Comment: Please explain why you are trying to add methods in this unusual way so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have a hw in OOP course they told us to add method in run time from a specific class to another class..

Comment: Not to repeat myself too much, but again *What context are you calling this in?* I voted to close the question based upon lack of enough code to properly reproduce the issue. You also need to edit your question and indicate the error you're getting in there, not just add it as a comment which is not very visible to other readers.

Comment: `primSize:` is a method in class `StandardFileStream` which is supposed to return the size of a file. When you evaluate a snippet of code, this snippet is written in the change log file associated with your image file (a file ending in `.changes`). Could it be possible that you don't have read access to the `.changes` file? What happens when you evaluate simpler snippets like `3+4`?

Answer (score 2):

this is actually a great excercise for learning that everything is an object in smalltalk :) The methods in the methodDictionary are simply instances of CompiledMethods which can be used in many ways .. i.e. manipulating classes at runtime, a way of reflective programming.

As for your question there is only a small error in your code. Instead of using methodDict use the methodDictionary accessor, then it should work fine. methodDict should not be accessed directly.

Here's a small playground you can execute in your pharo image. Just replace ClassA and B with your respective one. Afterwards you will see that the copied methods will persist and remain visible when browsing ClassB.

```
"list methods of ClassA and ClassB"
Transcript open; clear.
Transcript show: '**ClassA methodDictionary:', String crlf.
ClassA methodDictionary associationsDo:
    [:assoc | Transcript show: assoc value asString, String crlf].
Transcript show: '**ClassB methodDictionary (Before):', String crlf.
ClassB methodDictionary associationsDo:
    [:assoc | Transcript show: assoc value asString, String crlf].

"Transfer all methods of ClassA to ClassB"
ClassA methodDictionary associationsDo:
    [:assoc | ClassB methodDictionary at: assoc key put: assoc value].

"again .. list methods of ClassB"
Transcript show: '**ClassB methodDictionary (After):', String crlf.
ClassB methodDictionary associationsDo:
    [:assoc | Transcript show: assoc value asString, String crlf].
```